# Xamarin UI Tests wont run because Android SDK not found

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I've been trying to get Xamarin UI tests to pass but I cant even get them to initialize. When running the tests I get this message.

> System.Exception : Android SDK not found. Please install it and if it
> is still not located, please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable
> to point to the directory.
>
> Searched locations:
> Windows Registry
> C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk - Partial match. Found: zipalign, aapt, adb, android.jar Missing: apksigner [Source:ANDROID_HOME ]

What is frustrating is that the program seems to recognise that is has most of the files but it missing `apksigner`. But when I checked the android-sdk folder it does contain a `apksigner.bat` file inside the `build-tools` folder.

I have set the `ANDROID_HOME` environment in the system settings to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`
It may be important to note that I can run the android app in the emulator just fine, but I cant get the UITest project to get it to work.

Comment: You set the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable in correctly. Do you get the same error? Have you tried to delete the bin and obj folder to clean and rebuild or try to restart the PC? What is the error now?

Comment: I have restarted my PC and I get the same error. Also are you saying I set my environment variable correctly? or incorrectly? Because it says I am getting a partial match found with only a single file missing. But when I checked the file is located in the correct folder.

Comment: I get the same error. I believe it happened with latest version of Xamarin.UiTest. I target Android11, and to my knowledge they introduced a new way of signing "stuff". So Xamarin uses version 1, Android demands version 2.

Comment: Had the same issue. It's caused by Xamarin.UITest 3.0.14, with 3.0.13 still works fine. Please see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031511/xamarin-uitest-3-0-14-apksigner-not-found)

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047607/visual-studio-xamarin-uitest-system-exception-android-sdk-not-found-runnin/69815186#69815186

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.UITest 3.0.14 is currently broken. You need to revert to 3.0.13 as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66042299/5339264)